# How to link to URL of related object in DRF

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I’m making a music player with a DRF backend.

I have two models, one is Song and the other is TrackQueue

In the browser, the “nowplaying” instance of TrackQueue shows the meta of the queued song with a link to the file in its meta.

What I need now is a url that always produces that instance of the “nowplaying” TrackQueue (id=1)

What would that url be and how can I create it?

Thank you

models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class TrackQueue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    is_song = models.OneToOneField(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Song, TrackQueue

class SongSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ('id' ,'title', 'file')

class TrackQueueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TrackQueue
        fields = ('id' , 'title', 'is_song')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializers import SongSerializer 
from rest_framework import viewsets      
from .models import Song, TrackQueue
from music.serializers import SongSerializer, TrackQueueSerializer

class SongView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    serializer_class = SongSerializer   
    queryset = Song.objects.all()     

class TrackQueueView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    serializer_class = TrackQueueSerializer   
    queryset = TrackQueue.objects.all()
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to add a url parameter like `myurl.com/?nowplaying=1`?

Comment: Yes. I want a static url that I can add to a HTML audio element that always returns the url of the song that is index 1 if nowplaying